# hide privateKey from nodeJS on Heroku?

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku

I've integrate BrainTree Drop-in UI for checkout payment in nodeJS. It's only a demonstration that I needed to create. I had no issues, it was easy enough. The only thing that I would like to do is to hide merchantId, publicKey and privateKey from the code. I would like to add them directly in Heroku Config Vars. I know how to do all this in Python, but I have no idea how to do it in JavaScript. I show you the code changing the keys:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const braintree = require('braintree');

router.post('/', (req, res, next) => {
  const gateway = new braintree.BraintreeGateway({
    environment: braintree.Environment.Sandbox,
    // Use your own credentials from the sandbox Control Panel here
    merchantId: 'h43jgh5g3gl4543',
    publicKey: 'hj45j4h5lh45hl4h5l',
    privateKey: 'b5hbhbb45bhbh4kfndnfdkkfnd'
  });

  // Use the payment method nonce here
  const nonceFromTheClient = req.body.paymentMethodNonce;
  // Create a new transaction for $10
  const newTransaction = gateway.transaction.sale({
    amount: '10.00',
    paymentMethodNonce: nonceFromTheClient,
    options: {
      // This option requests the funds from the transaction
      // once it has been authorized successfully
      submitForSettlement: true
    }
  }, (error, result) => {
      if (result) {
        res.send(result);
      } else {
        res.status(500).send(error);
      }
  });
});

module.exports = router;
```

How can I assign those values to Variables that I can then pass to Heroku Config Vars?

Thank you very much for your help!

---

EDITING THE INTIAL POST:

---

Sorry I need to add more info about this post. I followed what a user suggested by changing the code in Node.js in this way:

```
router.post('/', (req, res, next) => {
  const gateway = new braintree.BraintreeGateway({
    environment: braintree.Environment.Sandbox,
    // Use your own credentials from the sandbox Control Panel here
    merchantId: process.env.MERCHANT_ID,
    publicKey: process.env.PUBLIC_KEY,
    privateKey: process.env.PRIVATE_KEY
  });
```

I added those value to Heroku, and it looked it was working, but I also changed the sandbox value in index.hbs:

```
<script>
  var button = document.querySelector('#submit-button');

  braintree.dropin.create({
    authorization: process.env.SANDBOX_KEY,
    container: '#dropin-container',
    paypal: {
      flow: 'checkout',
      buttonStyle: {
        color: 'blue',
        shape: 'rect',
        size: 'medium'
      },
      amount: '10.00',
      currency: 'USD'
    }
  },
```

I replace the value 'sanbox_34920hfjh34i23h4oi3' with process.env.SANDBOX_KEY and added that value in Heroku.

But now the interface doesn't work anymore, why?

Thank you very much for your precious help!

Answer (score 2):

You can add Config variables in Heroku dashboard or with the CLI more on that here [Configuration and Config Vars](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars). Now, when you done that you can access them in your Node app as `process.env.NAME_OF_VARIABLE`.

Comment: Config variables in Heroku are case sensitive, and a general rule is to put them all in capital letters and divide words by underscores `_`. So the name of the config variable that you put in Heroku e.g. `MERCHANT_ID` can be accessed in Node as `process.env.MERCHANT_ID`. There isn't much to go wrong here, make sure the spelling and uppercase are the same, and also if the Config vars in Heroku are saved when you reload the dashboard or acceess them in the CLI.